# Partial View in Asp.net mvc 3 Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i've a table name Info. i want to create a partial view of this table of a strongly typed.
my partial view in View/Shared is  _InfoView.cshtl like:

```
 @model IEnumerable<RealTest.Models.ifo>

  <h2>_InfoView</h2>

 <p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
 </p>
  <table>
      <tr>
         <th>
           name
       </th>
      <th>
         address
       </th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.address)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
   </tr>
 }
```

my View page is like:
     @model IEnumerable

```
 @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
 <p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
  </p>

   @Html.Partial("_InfoView")
```

now i want to call it from another strongly typed view. when i called it it seems that it didn't get required data for partial view.now how i should pass partial view data???

Answer (score 0):

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("is _InfoView", model);}
```

where your model would need to be a collection of ifo objects.

Comment: please describe little bit more please...?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this

```
@Html.Partial("ProdItemColors",Model.PropertyName)
```

For example, If you have a `ViewModel` called `Customer` which has a Collection property of type `Info` like this

```
public class Customer
{
  public string CustomerName { set;get;}
  public IList<Info> InfoItems { set;get;}

  public Customer()
  {
      InfoItems=new List<Info>();
  }
}
public class Info()
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
}
```

Now from your main view which is bounded to your `Customer` class, you can call it like this

```
@model Customer
<p>@Model.CustomerName </p>
@Html.Partial("_InfoView",Model.InfoItems)
```

Assuming you have a View called _InfoView.cshtml either in the `~/Views/Shared` folder or `~/Views/YourcontrollerName` folder.

Make sure your Partial view is bounded to Info class

```
@model IEnumerable<Info>
<p>do something inside this</p>
```

Comment: actually i've 2 model inside Customer class.i call 2 partial view but it gives error **The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RealTest.Models.accc]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RealTest.Models.ifo]'.**

Comment: That means your view is buunded to Ifo class and you the property you are passing to it is of type accc class.